# Accessing getters and setters of a function that implements an interface

Tags: java, inheritance

Referring to the following code:

```
FeedDAO mongoFeedDao = new MongoFeedDAOImpl(feedData);

// Inserting feed data to the database
mongoFeedDao.insert();

String id = mongoFeedDao.getId();
```

MongoFeedDAOImpl implements FeedDAO, and there is a getter in MongoFeedDAOImpl which I want to access but I am not being able to. Following is the getter:

```
public String getDocumentID() {
    return documentID;
}
```

and following is my class definition

```
public class MongoFeedDAOImpl implements FeedDAO {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to access a method that is specific to MongoFeedDAOImpl, and not in the interface, your variable must be of type MongoFeedDAOImpl:

```
MongoFeedDAOImpl mongoFeedDao = new MongoFeedDAOImpl(feedData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can cast to MongoFeedDAOImpl.

```
FeedDAO mongoFeedDao = new MongoFeedDAOImpl(feedData);
mongoFeedDao = (MongoFeedDAOImpl) mongoFeedDao;
```

or

```
MongoFeedDAOImpl mongoFeedDao = new MongoFeedDAOImpl(feedData);
```